# angular, get access on native element by passed referefence

Tags: angular

Can I pass an ElementRef to a child-component and then access its nativeElement there?
I get the html element but I have no access to the nativeElement. What i can do to have access on nativeElement or how can i pass it directly?

parent template:

```
<tr #refTr1>
  <app-cell [parentRef]="refTr1"></app-cell>
</tr>
```

the child component "appCellComponent":

```
@Input parentRef: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.parentRef.nativeElement.classList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot () after @Input decorator

and your property type is HTMLTableRowElement;

```
@Input() parentRef: HTMLTableRowElement;
```

and you don't need to use **nativeElement** after **this.parentRef**

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need the nativeElement because i work in the child with the MutationObserver and it needs the nativeElement. Sorry, I didn't mention that. I can instantiate the nativeElement myself and pass the HTMLTableRowElement to the constructor. As I understand it, nativeElement is independently instantiated by specifying the decorator @ViewChild(). But in my way i must do it manually. What you mean? Can I solve it bether? Best regards.

Comment: your welcome. why do you want to observe your <tr> element for changes? I never see someone use  MutationObserver to see DOM changes in angular framework. by the way HTMLTableRowElement is just a type and your parentRef is native  element and I read MutationObserver document it seem it will work in it